# Copy Data from One Tab to Another without Blanks

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to copy Data from One Tab to Another. Just to Demonstrate.

Sheet1 has in Column E, the following Data:

```
abc
def

efg
hig
```

DataDump Sheet should contain (notice how there are no blanks). All of this should be done via app script:

```
abc
def
efg
hig
```

This is the formula that I have so far.

```
function copyInfo() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var copySheet = ss.getSheet1ByName("Sheet");
  var pasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("DataDump");
  
  var source = copySheet.getRange(1,5,6000,1);

  if(source != ""){
  
  var destination = pasteSheet.getRange(pasteSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,5000,1);
  
  source.copyTo(destination);

  }
  
  }
```

The above formula is what I have tried so far.

Comment: Please provide a table showing all five columns including column E

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
function copyInfo() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh0 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const sh1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const vs = sh0.getRange(1, 5, sh0.getLastRow()).getValues().filter(e => e[0]);
  sh1.getRange(1,1,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}
```